# How do we resolve the InvalidScheduleVersion error?

Tags: polkadot-js, error, pallet-contracts, contracts

From the [contracts pallet](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/488fc24d98cfe643402b86990ae0aff27ba927b3/frame/contracts/src/lib.rs#L751-L754):

```
        /// A new schedule must have a greater version than the current one.
        InvalidScheduleVersion,
```

The context of this error is sending batch transactions from polkadot-js.

`api.tx.utility.batchAll(txs)`

Presumably these are being scheduled using the schedule pallet?

I'm using the substrate-contracts-node 0.23.0-430873a4fbe

Comment: This error does nothing in the latest code. What's your Substrate version?

Comment: I found this: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blame/59494855205374e8f27fb131425dfd78897a9298/frame/contracts/src/lib.rs#LL530-L530C5

Comment: Thanks, I'm using substrate-contracts-node 0.23.0-ac615c91892

Comment: Sorry that was wrong. I'm on the most recent substrate-contracts-node 0.23.0-430873a4fbe

Comment: The raw error data is `{ Module: { index: '19', error: '0x02000000' } }`. Do you know where I can find the corresponding error the substrate code?

Comment: Ok, looks like its `OutOfGas` but for some reason polkadot JS is passing back the wrong error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an issue in the translation of the error data to the error message when using the following `findMetaError` from polkadot-js.

```
const mod = dispatchError.asModule
const error = this.api.registry.findMetaError(
    new Uint8Array([mod.index.toNumber(), new BN(mod.error).toNumber()])
)
```

Because the hexadecimal `mod.error` is `0x02000000`, the decimal representation of this is `33554432`, which is not one of the indices in the [pallet contracts errors](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/polkadot-js/api/v9.12.1/packages/types-support/src/metadata/v14/substrate-types.json) (search for `523` in this file).

Presumably, the hexadecimal used to index should have been `0x02`, which converts to index `2` and `OutOfGas`.

```
> util.bnFromHex('0x02000000').toNumber()
33554432
> util.bnFromHex('0x02').toNumber()
2
```

```
  {
    "id": 523,
    "type": {
      "path": [
        "pallet_contracts",
        "pallet",
        "Error"
      ],
      "params": [
        {
          "name": "T",
          "type": null
        }
      ],
      "def": {
        "variant": {
          "variants": [

            ...

            {
              "name": "OutOfGas",
              "fields": [],
              "index": 2,
              "docs": [
                "The executed contract exhausted its gas limit."
              ]
            },
```

EDIT: it looks like the additional bytes [can include error details](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/1983/380).