# How to decode an error that happened in a proxy.proxy call

Tags: polkadot-js, decode, pallet-proxy

I'd like to show my users if an error occurred while doing a proxy.proxy call.
While I know how to decode a `system.ExtrinsicFailed`, as this is [well documented](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/api/cookbook/tx#how-do-i-get-the-decoded-enum-for-an-extrinsicfailed-event), I have difficulties finding the correct way to decode an error from `proxy.ProxyExecuted` when printed to string, it shows `[{"err":{"module":{"index":4,"error":"0x02000000"}}}]` when there's an error or `[{"ok": null}]` in case it succeeded.

What would be the best way to check the status and decode the error?

I am ideally looking at something similar than

```
const [dispatchError] = data
const decoded = api.registry.findMetaError((dispatchError as any).asModule);
const errorInfo = `${decoded.docs} - ${decoded.section}.${decoded.name}`;
```

But checking if `dispatchError.err` exists or forcing it with `asModule` doesn't end well, although it looks like a module. It needs a step in between to be decoded it seems, that I'm missing.

Comment: Did you strip the trailing zeroes from the `0x02000000` before encoding it as a number? e.g. use `0x02`. The other zeroes are for [extra error data](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/1983/380).

Answer (score 2):

Thanks a lot forgetso for your help. this definitely got me on the right track. For some reason, the `asModule` didn't work. I had subsequent TS errors such as `toNumber` is not a function.

I had to use `toJSON` to what came back from the event to work my way through. That's the working code:

```js
const [dispatchError]: any = data.toJSON();

// if proxy has an error
if (dispatchError?.err?.module) {
  const mod = dispatchError.err.module
  const error = api.registry.findMetaError(
    new Uint8Array([Number(mod.index), Number(mod.error.slice(0, 4))])
  )

  errorInfo = Array.isArray(error.docs) ? error.docs.join('') : error.docs || ''
}
```

Comment: Glad you got it sorted. If you're getting TS errors like `x` doesn't exist on `Codec` you can use [this guide](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/api/FAQ/#since-upgrading-to-the-7x-series-typescript-augmentation-is-missing).

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to strip the trailing zeroes from the error code and decode the error as follows:

```
            const mod = dispatchError.asModule
            const error = api.registry.findMetaError(
                new Uint8Array([mod.index.toNumber(), bnFromHex(mod.error.toHex().slice(0, 4)).toNumber()])
            )
            message = `${error.section}.${error.name}${
                Array.isArray(error.docs) ? `(${error.docs.join('')})` : error.docs || ''
            }`
```

This will give you the module at index 4, error with index 2. e.g. in substrate

```
node_modules/@polkadot/types-support/metadata/v14/substrate-json.json

        {
          "name": "Authorship",
    
          ...

          "errors": {
            "type": 424 // use this value to look for the errors
          },
          "index": 4
        },
```

```
node_modules/@polkadot/types-support/metadata/v14/substrate-types.json
  {
    "id": 424,
    "type": {
      "path": [
        "pallet_authorship",
        "pallet",
        "Error"
      ],
      ...
      "def": {
        "variant": {
          "variants": [
      ...
            {
              "name": "TooManyUncles", // this might be your error
              "fields": [],
              "index": 2,
              "docs": [
                "Too many uncles."
              ]
            },
```